# no viable alternative at input ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm designing a language that allows you to make predicates on data. Here is my lexer.

```
lexer grammar Studylexer;


fragment LETTER : [A-Za-z];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment TWODIGIT : DIGIT DIGIT;
fragment MONTH:  ('0' [1-9] | '1' [0-2]);
fragment DAY: ('0' [1-9] | '1' [1-9] | '2' [1-9] | '3' [0-1]);



TIMESTAMP: TWODIGIT ':' TWODIGIT; // représentation de la timestamp 

DATE : TWODIGIT TWODIGIT MONTH DAY; // représentation de la date


ID : LETTER+; // match identifiers 

STRING : '"' ( ~ '"' )* '"' ; // match string content

NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ; // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)

WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace 

LIST: ( LISTSTRING | LISTDATE | LISTTIMESTAMP ) ; // list of variabels;

// list of operators

GT: '>';
LT: '<';
GTEQ: '>=';
LTEQ:'<=';
EQ: '=';
IN: 'in';

fragment LISTSTRING: STRING ',' STRING (',' STRING)*; // list of strings
fragment LISTDATE : DATE   ',' DATE   (',' DATE)*;    // list of dates
fragment LISTTIMESTAMP:TIMESTAMP ',' TIMESTAMP (',' TIMESTAMP )*; // list of timestamps
    
NAMES: 'filename' | 'timestamp' | 'tso' | 'region' | 'processType' | 'businessDate' | 'lastModificationDate'; // name of variables in the where block

KEY: ID '[' NAMES ']' | ID '.' NAMES; // predicat key
```

and here is a part of my grammar.

```
expr: KEY op = ('>' | '<') value = (  DATE  | TIMESTAMP )  NEWLINE          # exprGTORLT
    | KEY op = ('>='| '<=') value = ( DATE  | TIMESTAMP )  NEWLINE          #  exprGTEQORLTEQ
    | KEY  '=' value = ( STRING | DATE      | TIMESTAMP )  NEWLINE          # exprEQ
    | KEY 'in'   LIST                                      NEWLINE          #exprIn
```

When I make a predicate for example.

```
tab [key]  in  "value1", "value2"
```

ANTLR generates an error.

> no viable alternative at input  tab [key]  in

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You are trying to use ID as both a lexer fragment rule and lexer token. So, in your rules, ID matches "tab" first and returns that token. Then, it comes across "[", and it doesn't know what that is, so it outputs an error. Then, it comes across "key", which matches ID, and returns ID token. What you want is change lexer rule "KEY" to parser rule "key", and use that in "expr" rule. After that, you have "NAMES" defined ("filename", "timestamp", etc), but "key" is not a valid alternative. I highly recommend you print out the token stream and parse tree so you can work past these problems.

Comment: @kaby76 I agree that `key` should almost certainly be a parser rule, but it is not true that `ID` will match the `tab` in `tab [key]` no matter what. If we use an input that actually matches the `KEY` rule (like `tab[filename]` for example), that will indeed produce a `KEY` token. The fact that `ID` could match `tab` doesn't interfere with that because longer matches are given precedence as per the maximal munch rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `tab [key]` does not produce a `KEY` token like you want it to for two reasons:

1. It contains spaces and `KEY` doesn't allow any spaces. The best way to fix that would be to remove the `KEY` rule from your lexer and instead turn it into a parser rule (meaning you also need to turn `[` and `]` into their own tokens). Then the white space in your input would be between tokens and thus successfully skipped.
2. `key` is not actually one of the words listed in `NAMES`.

Then another issue is that `in` is recognized as an `ID` token, not an `IN` token. That's because both `ID` and `IN` would produce a match of the same length and in cases like that the rule that's listed first takes precedence. So you should define `ID` after all of the keywords because otherwise the keywords will never be matched.